# xCode loses connection to device when running app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have been building an iOS app and have been testing it both on the simulator as well as my iPad. Everything was working perfectly until-
when i recently added the code to register for push notifications to my **AppDelegate.m** file. Now when I try to run the app on the device the app lingers on the splash screen for a while and then xCode comes up with the following error.

> process launch failed: timed out waiting for app to launch

and here's the code i added, Just in case :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
 // Override point for customization after application launch.

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 80000
   if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
   {
      UIUserNotificationType userNTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound);

      UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNTypes categories:nil];

        NSLog(@"sherikkum registering 8.xx...");

      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
   }
   else
   {
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: 
      (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
#else
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
   (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

#endif

return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
  NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);

  //I added this alert coz i couldnt view NSLogs - coz my xcode wont connect
  UIAlertView *tokenalert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Token"
                                                     message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken]
                                                    delegate:nil
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
  [tokenalert show];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
{
   NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: To make sure its because of the notification related code, remove it and run the app again. Also I didn't understand why did you a use macro (__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED) and not the method [[UIDevice current device] system version]. This macro will detect the OS version at compile time instead of run-time which may create problems.

Comment: Updated my answer again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be using a Distribution Certificate instead of Developer Certificate while running your app. Change it in **Target => Build Settings=> Code Signing**.

[image]

If you are using a provisioning profile created from a distribution certificate, your code will not run on a device running from xcode. You need to use a provisioning profile created from a development certificate. For further details on provisioning profiles and certificates please read [Apple's Documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppStoreDistributionTutorial/CreatingYourTeamProvisioningProfile/CreatingYourTeamProvisioningProfile.html)

Comment: How do I know if thats the case and how do i change it? This is my first full Project and i'm not very familiar with certificates.

Comment: bdw... that seems to have been the problem... I reverted my Provisioning profile to automatic and that did the trick. but sooner or later, I need to get to know better about certificates, profiles, tests. etc. So can you give me some tips on that, any links to good tutorials would also be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: There are many but my favorite is http://www.raywenderlich.com/2915/ios-code-signing-under-the-hood